# How to use java generics with restTemplate

Tags: java, generics, resttemplate

I have an execute method that I've created where I pass in my restTemplate instance along with the class obj. However, I'm getting some warnings about unchecked types. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with generics. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class RepositoryUtils {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RepositoryUtils.class);

    public static ResponseEntity execute(String url, RestTemplate restTemplate, Class generic) {

        LOGGER.info("GET: {}", url);

        ResponseEntity response = null;
        try {
            response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, RequestHelper.getGzipHttpEntity(), generic);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("RestTemplate: {} - {}", url, e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

And here is how I make a call to my static execute:

```
ResponseEntity<Channels> response = RepositoryUtils.execute(channelUrlFinal, restTemplate, Channels.class);
```

Comment: Please let us know the exact error and the location. My guess is you need to change the method signature to `public static ResponseEntity execute(String url, RestTemplate restTemplate, Class<?> generic) {`

Comment: @jhyot I'm not getting an error but two warnings instead. When I'm calling my execute method I get an unchecked assignment warning since I'm expecting a ResponseEntity<Channels> even though my method only returns ResponseEntity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you could try as signature of your method:

```
public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> execute(String url, RestTemplate restTemplate, 
    Class<T> generic) {
```